# expected primary-expression before ')' token in c language

Tags: c, syntax-error

I'm practicing selection sort and copying the code from data structure by Horowitz.
I'm dealing with the error of "expected primary-expression before ')' token."

Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define compare(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? -1 : ((x) == (y)) ? 0 : 1))

int binsearch(int list[], int searchnum, int left, int right)
{
int middle; 
while(left <= right){
    middle = (left + right) / 2;
    switch(compare(list[middle], searchnum)){   //  error occured
        case -1: right = middle -1; break;
        case 0: return middle;
        case 1: left = middle + 1;
    }
}   
return -1; 
}
```

I want to know what I should do to solve this problem.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohdAlomar I edited as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> #define compare(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? -1 : ((x) == (y)) ? 0 : 1))
> ```

This macro has an extra closing parenthesis at the end. Make it:

```
#define compare(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? -1 : ((x) == (y)) ? 0 : 1)
```

You can also get rid of the parentheses around the `<` and `==` comparisons if you like.

```
#define compare(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? -1 : (x) == (y) ? 0 : 1)
```